# select2 4.0 bootstrap responsiveness broken when long text option is selected

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

It seems like selecting an option with very long text makes the select2 container grow.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxbbph6h/1/

To reproduce the problem:

1) Resize the browser to a small width

2) Select the last option on the dropdown

HTML:

```
  <body>
  <div role="main" class="col-sm-9 ef-middle-column">
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="myDropdown">dropdown</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select 
            id="myDropdown"
            style="max-width:200px"
            name="myDropdown"
            >
              <option value="One">One</option>
              <option value="Two">Two</option>
              <option value="Three-Thirty">Three-Thirty (£69.00)</option>
              <option value="Twenty-Two">Twenty-Two</option>
              <option value="One hundred and lots more numbers after this to see what happens with long text">One hundred and
              lots more numbers after this to see what happens with long text</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myDropdown').select2();
```

CSS:

```
[class*="col-"] .select2-container {
        width:89%!important;
        max-width: 481px;
    }
```